# Passing in an anonymous method/function as a parameter in C#

Tags: c#, anonymous-function, anonymous-methods

I have a method that needs to conditionally execute a method, something like this:

```
int MyMethod(Func<int> someFunction)
{
    if (_someConditionIsTrue)
    {
        return someFunction;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to be able to pass a Linq query in to MyMethod as someFunction:

```
int i = MyMethod(_respository.Where(u => u.Id == 1).Select(u => u.OtherId));
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int i = MyMethod(() => _respository.Where(u => u.Id == 1).Select(u => u.OtherId));
```

As you can see, I've made the query into a lambda. You will have to do this because otherwise, your query will be executed just before calling `MyMethod` (...and will introduce compile-time errors ;) ) and not while it executes.

*A side note:*

This `return someFunction;` should be `return someFunction();`.

Comment: Doh! I almost had it this way, but I had `() = _repository` instead of `() => _respository`.  This works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @Jerad Rose I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's a typo, but in MyMethod you need to actually call the function:

```
        return someFunction();
```

And when calling it, you're calling the function directly. Instead you need to pass a lambda expression. Also, you seem to be passing in a `Func<IEnumerable<int>>`; add `Single()`, `SingleOrDefault()`, `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
int i = MyMethod(() => _respository.Where(u => u.Id == 1).Select(u => u.OtherId).SingleOrDefault());
```